# Getting an error while sending message to ActiveMQ Queue from wso2

Tags: json, api, wso2, activemq-classic

I am trying to send message to ActiveMQ Queue from WSO2 with help of below API:

```
<resource methods="GET">
     <inSequence>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="Bashir bhhhh" value="Service"/>
            </log>
            <call>
                <endpoint key="check_ep"/>
            </call>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="Bashir bhhhh" value="Service Ends"/>
            </log>
        </inSequence>
    </resource>
```

The message is delivering to the queue but when I terminate the request from postman I get this error. Unable to figure out what is this error and how can it be resolved. Clarifying that message is delivering to the ActiveMQ queue but the request is not ending, and on terminating manually from postman getting this error.

```
ERROR {JMSSender} - Did not receive a JMS response within 30000 ms to destination : temp-queue://ID:IBM-PF3K6KLP-59783-1674314596400-1:2:1 with JMS correlation ID : ID:IBM-PF3K6KLP-59783-1674314596400-1:2:1:1:1
ERROR {Axis2Sender} - {api:finch} Unexpected error during sending message out java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Any help would mean a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For JMS Producing scenarios, you need to set the following property.

```
<property action="set" name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
```

```xml
<resource methods="GET">
 <inSequence>
        <log level="custom">
            <property name="Bashir bhhhh" value="Service"/>
        </log>
        <property action="set" name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
        <call>
            <endpoint key="check_ep"/>
        </call>
        <log level="custom">
            <property name="Bashir bhhhh" value="Service Ends"/>
        </log>
    </inSequence>
</resource>
```

If you want to do a guaranteed delivery scenario you can check JMS Dual channel example [here](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.0.0/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/jms_examples/dual-channel-http-to-jms/).